# creating a self signed ssl in ii7 on windows 7

Tags: facebook, iis-7, ssl

I need to create a self signed certificate to test a facebook app. i tried to follow the steps on the [microsoft web site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127%28WS.10%29.aspx) however where it says in iis7 features view 'select server certificates' i don't have this option in the features view.

Answer (score 0):

Here are screen shots for this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: great thanks. after i create the certificate then go to bind it to the website and it stops the site. when i try to start the site i get 'the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020) when i unbind the SSL I can then start the site again with no error